# Mailchimp - How to record data to subscribers list from 2 different forms

Tags: mailchimp

Ho everyone, I'm in trouble with my campaign, this happened to me... when i go to my list to see the data of the recipients.

It is asking me to create a reconfirmation Campaign, due to a too high volume of unsubscribed to this campaign.

Here the path I've been following to realise my campaign ( It is the first time I'm using Mailchimp):

I have an invitation to a event where guest can approve or decline the invitation.

When they Accept the invitation: it bring to the update profile form - which icahnge in the advence editor. This way We can record some data such as dietary requirements,etc which would be recorder to our subscriber list ons submit.

When people decline the invitation, we have link to the unsubscribe form. This way we are able to know Which person has decline the invitation.

From what I understand, this is way It stopped our campaign.

What I'm looking to achieve . . . and din't manage i slept 2 hours last night trying to make this work . .. and i m in a big rush :

How can I achieve to collect data with the path explain previously, without having this issue in the future - so without using the unsubscribe from - but two different forms ?

How can I access to the List of User who have accept the invitation, so I mean the Subscriber List. because since that happen, I can't access it - and obviously i don't want to send another email to the guests asking them to fill up again.

I really appreciate all the help that anybody can provide me with that,

Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're trying to use list subscriptions to stand-in for RSVPs? That is likely to look really bad -- ESPs see high volumes of unsubscribes as suspiciously spammy -- you'd be better off using Interests or Merge Fields on your list to denote the user's RSVP rather than asking them to unsubscribe. As for your current account, follow the instructions in the email you received if you want to get your list back up and running again.